# Running Composer Inside a Docker From Jenkinsfile Container Wrecks Permissions

Tags: docker, jenkins, composer-php

I'm working on setting up Jenkins to run phpunit inside a Docker container so I can easily reset the working environment.  An extremely slimmed down version of this is below.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        dockerfile {
            args '-u root:root '
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'php composer.phar install'
                sh 'phpunit'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The trouble I'm having is that when it runs `composer install` the  owner of the created files is being set to root:root on the host which then causes the process that cleans up the old builds to be unable to delete the files.  Is there a way to have composer run inside the container and have them be owned by jenkins:jenkins on the host?

Thanks!